# Spring: multiple instances of the same class; number and properties based on config

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, app-config

here's the setup. customer is allowed to define some config of the app in the following form:

```
A.p1=foo
A.p2=bar
B.p1=baz
B.p2=qux
...
```

The number of configurations (A, B, ...) is not known upfront.
Each valid configuration should result in a new bean (all of the same type), for end result of

```
MyBean
  p1=foo
  p2=bar
MyBean
  p1=baz
  p2=qux
...
```

These are standalone executors, so I don't think I'll need to refer to them anywhere. 
I could do all this in code, but perhaps I'm missing a more elegant solution? I'm rubbish with Spring.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: you want to create multiple instances with different configuration of the some class ?

Comment: @happy, Your question is not clear. Add some comments or edit your question.

Comment: @Sarma Apologies, I edited the question to hopefully make it clear - Jigar Joshi is right - it is the same class, just different configurations.